# How to simplify $-\sqrt {16x^2}$ when $x < 0$?

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

What is $-\sqrt {16x^2}$ when $x < 0$?

Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What do you get when $x = -1$?

Comment: $\sqrt {16x^2} = \sqrt {(4x)^2} = |4x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, the expression $\sqrt {x^2}$ equals $|x|$. Then, we got that:
$$-\sqrt{16x^2}=-\sqrt{16}\cdot\sqrt{x^2}=-4\cdot|x|.$$
Now, since $|x|=-x$ for all $x<0$, we conclude that:
$$x<0\implies -\sqrt{16x^2}=\boxed{4x}$$